# Exchange ECP mail flow subject with forward slash issue

Tags: exchange

I want to set up a rule that when the subject contains with /#### (e.g. /1234) then do something. At Outlook or OWA works fine. However, when I tried to do it at Exchange ECP Mail Flow....No matter how hard I try, still cannot make it work....:(

I've tried
/1234 - not work
[/1234] - not work
/1234 - not work
"/1234" - not work

I've been googling for 3 days still can't find a solution yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use _ instead of / at the rule can fix this issue.
When I export the mail (drag and drop) the message to the desktop with the subject "test/123/234", the file name will be shown as "test_123_234"
As a result, when you want to look for "/123" at the subject, set the rule to look for "_123"  at the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information you need by googling for how to use regular expressions in exchange transport rules. The syntax is not the same.

Try: `/\d\d\d\d`

**Pattern matching in Exchange Transport Rules**

- `\S` The \S pattern string matches any single character that's not a
  space.
- `\s` The \s pattern string matches any single white-space character.
- `\D` The \D pattern string matches any non-numeric digit.
- `\d` The \d pattern string matches any single numeric digit.
- `\w` The \w pattern string matches any single Unicode character categorized as a letter or decimal digit.
- `\W` The \W pattern string matches any single Unicode character not categorized as a letter or a decimal digit.
- `|` The pipe ( | ) character performs an OR function.
- `*` The asterisk ( * ) character matches zero or more instances of the previous character. For example, ab*c matches the following strings: ac, abc, abbbbc.
- `( )` Parentheses act as grouping delimiters. For example, a(bc)* matches the following strings: a, abc, abcbc, abcbcbc, and so on.
- `\` A backslash is used as an escaping character before a special character. Special characters are characters used in pattern strings:

  - Backslash `\`
  - Pipe  `|`
  - Asterisk `*`
  - Opening parenthesis `(`
  - Closing parenthesis `)`
  - Caret `^`
  - Dollar sign `$` For example, if you want to match a string that contains (525), you would type `\(525\)`.
- `^` The caret ( ^ ) character indicates that the pattern string that follows the caret must exist at the start of the text string being matched. For example, ^fred@contoso matches fred@contoso.com and fred@contoso.co.uk but not alfred@contoso.com.
- `$` The dollar sign ( $ ) character indicates that the preceding pattern string must exist at the end of the text string being matched. 
  For example, contoso.com$ matches adam@contoso.com and kim@research.contoso.com, but doesn't match kim@contoso.com.au

http://blog.chrislehr.com/2014/11/using-regular-expressions-in-exchange.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I've been looking for it. But I can't find a way to deal with a forward slash :(
Let say the subject is "ABC001/1234/2345"
If my rule just looks for "1234" then prepend something to the subject, it works fine. But if the rule looks for "/1234"  then it does not prepend anything to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in my Exchange 2013 lab and got the same result. After researching, I created a new text file named 'slash' and type/1234 in it. Then I wrote a script like below:

$Keywords=Import-Content "C:\temp\slash.txt"
New-TransportRule -Name "redirect with slash" -SubjectOrBodyContainsWords $Keywords -RedirectMessageTo user004

Ran the script via EMS. It will read in the content of keywords into a variable, create a mail flow rule that redirecting messages to user004, and assign the variable with the keywords to the mail flow rule condition. It might return an error, just ignore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAj8Q.png)

I opened Outlook, sent a message subject including  '/1234' to user003. Result as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQkjw.png)

Since we don’t know what rule actions you want to deploy, you can modify the script according to your own circumstances. The KB for your reference:

**Set-TransportRule**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/policy-and-compliance/set-transportrule?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not familiar with Exchange Server.

You mean I have to put the Keyword to a text file?

If I want to redirect a mail to User A when matching "/1234" and redirect to User B when match "/2345", then I have to create 2 text files?

The .ps1 file just need to run once or I need to set a task at the task scheduler to run it from time to time?

When the keyword contains a forward slash "/" can never be defined it directly at the New-TransportRule?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want to set multiple transport rules, it needs to create text files and run scripts independently. I tested in my lab if adding slash symbol directly in the New-TransportRule, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot K_D117 :) 
Last question, I just need to run the script once to import the keyword?

Comment: Yep,  you can run the script once to import the keyword.

Comment: I just tried. It did create a rule but the rule does not contain any keyword. It just redirect all the mail to the user

Comment: I changed the import-content to get-content and it can import the keyword but the rule also cannot recognize the forward slash

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. After my testing, this transport rule setting: "The subject or body... subject matches these text patterns"  it could distinguish slash character, and only takes effect for it.

Comment: doesn't matter, I will try to look for other solution in the coming SAT/SUN. Hope I can fix it this week.

Comment: use _ instead of / at the rule can fix this issue.
When I export the mail (drap and drop) the message to the desktop with the subject "test/123/234", the file name will be shown as "test_123_234"
As a result, when you want to look for "/123" at the subject, set the rule to look for "_123"  at the subject.